# EasyMock: Expect Number of Elements in a Set

Tags: java, easymock

How do you verify the number of elements in a set in Easymock?  The class I'm testing should call a method, passing in a set with *n* elements.  Right now, I'm matching any object for the list:

```
    mockFooSetReceiver.saveFooSet(eq(name), 
            (List<IFooSet>) anyObject());
    replay(mockFooSetReceiver);
```

What I'd like to specify the number of elements in the set:

```
    mockFooSetReceiver.saveFooSet(eq(name), 
            setOfNObject(100));
    replay(mockFooSetReceiver);
```

Or better yet, match the elements in the set:

```
    mockFooSetReceiver.saveFooSet(eq(name), 
            setEq(ecpectedSet));
    replay(mockFooSetReceiver);
```

Do I have to roll my own matcher, of is there one built in?  Or does someone have a `setOfNObject` or `setEq` matcher that they'd like to share?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Sets must implement equals(..) according to this contract:

> Compares the specified object with this set for equality.  Returns
>   true if the specified object is also a set, the two sets
>   have the same size, and every member of the specified set is
>   contained in this set (or equivalently, every member of this set is
>   contained in the specified set).  This definition ensures that the
>   equals method works properly across different implementations of the
>   set interface.

a simple EasyMock.eq(ecpectedSet) does the job.

If it's only the size of the set @Guillaume's answer is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks, that works great.  Much easier than making my own matcher.

Answer (score 1):

You have to design your own matcher and in the `matches` method:

1. check the number of arguments
2. cast the set argument to a Set
3. check the length

Sorry I have no similar matcher at hand.